# Validation Pattern MUMPS where string has space

Tags: mumps

working to create a program in M that check if the string ends with 5 numeric characters

```
i address?5.N s error="" w "Error:",error q 1
s error="invalid" q0
```

The above code works for string like "12345" but not for "ABCD 12345"

How can i handle the space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `address?.E5N`. 0-n of everything, and 5 numbers exactly.